# Completely remove visible border on JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, jbutton

Can anyone tell me how to remove this yellow pointed border around button?

[image]

Following methods didn't do the job.

```
btnPdf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
btnPdf.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btnPdf.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be caused by the button having focus. Try adding

```
btnPdf.setFocusPainted(false);
```